# How to update all instances of field with a santitized copy of another field

Tags: 7, database

I want have added an extra field to a table and want to use `db_update` in `hook_update_N` to populate it with a sanitized copy of a *preexisting* field.

Just copying a pre-existing field is trivial if one uses `db_update()`.

```
db_update('my_table')
  ->expression('field_copyof_unsafe_value', 'field_unsafe_value')
  ->execute();
```

However, what I want to do something like this:

```
db_update('my_table')
  ->expression('field_plain_value', check_plain('field_unsafe_value'))
  ->execute();
```

I.e. pass the value of `field_unsafe_value` through some function before storing it in the new field.

For avoidance of misunderstanding: I know the code above will *not* work (and that it will throw an exception).  It is pseudo-code to illustrate what I want to achieve.

My question is: Is it possible to use a function call in `db_update()` to compute value to store, and if "yes": How to do it?

Comment: Only if it’s a MySQL function, otherwise you’ll need to SELECT the existing data, loop through it and update. Also bear in mind there are revision tables, those need to be updated too

Comment: @Clive. Thanks! I've already written a loop using SELECT. It just seems so clunky. At least it is good to know that I don't need to waste more time looking for this.

Comment: The Drupal convention is to sanitize during output not input.

Comment: @NoSssweat. I know. The question is about using a function call in `db_update()` . Sanitation is only used as an *example*, as I assumed that the PHP function `check_plain()` is well known do Drupal developers.